# QWaitCondition, except with manual reset? (Or creating QFuture objects outside of Qt Concurrent?)

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

Does Qt provide a synchronization primitive that behaves in much the same way as [Concurrency::event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492846.aspx) from Microsoft's Concurrency Runtime?

Specifically, I would like wait() in thread A to return even if it does not call wait() until after thread B has already called wakeAll(), but before a "reset" function is called.  Also, I'd like something where reset() and set() do not have to be called from the same thread.

Basically, if I did not need to have async operations run in a specific thread (in my case it basically feeding tasks to an OpenGL rendering thread) QFuture and Qt Concurrent would be perfect.

If not specifically provided, is there a way to emulate that functionality with Qt?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought that I needed a QFuture a few times in the past as well, but always ended up using signals and slots to pass messages between the threads, carrying the data I would have put in the QFuture as an argument. Especially when there's a QEventLoop at the bottom of my thread.

Without an event loop I usually end up doing it manually with QWaitCondition, QMutex and QMutexLocker.

So sadly I would say that there isn't any higher-level class that would fit what you describe.

Answer (score 0):

So now you have the mutex and the wait condition.

Simply add a boolean flag, which you access with the same mutex locked.

When you do `wakeAll`, also set flag to true. Before doing `wait`, check the flag first and don't wait it is true. And then reset is simply setting the flag to false.